# Can we modify this argument correctly and easily? ("Postmodern Analysis Third Edition" by Juergen Jost)

Tags: solution-verification, exponential-function

I am reading "Postmodern Analysis Third Edition" by Juergen Jost.

The following is on p.8.

> The exponential function is given by $$e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{x}{n})^n.$$ It is strictly monotonically increasing, i.e. $$e^x<e^y\text{ for }x<y.$$ (This follows from the fact that for each $n$ $$(1+\frac{x}{n})^n=1+x+\text{other positive terms}$$ that are increasing in $x$, and consequently $(1+\frac{y}{n})^n-(1+\frac{x}{n})^n\geq y-x$ for $x<y$.)

I think this argument is not right:
Let $f(x):=(1+\frac{x}{2})^2$.
Then, $-4<-2$ and $f(-4)=1>0=f(-2)$.

Can we modify the above argument correctly and easily?

Comment: I can't see how.  Also, this is a rather weird definition of $e^x$.  (How does Jost prove that the limit even converges?)  Most authors choose to define $\exp(x)$ in terms of its Taylor series.  I.e.
$$\exp(x) = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{6} + \cdots.$$

Comment: @JosephCamacho Thank you very much for your comment. The author didn't prove that the limit converges.

Comment: He’s clearly restricting to $x>0$.

Comment: @Deane Thank you very much for your comment.